# Optimized query in join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1890) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'cat'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;
```

Is it possible to convert it to a join query in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using joins, just using a bad syntax for it.  You query should look like this:

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu
from val_tb  a join
     carin b
     on a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id join
     mapos c
     on b.posd = c.posid
where a.VA_record_id in (Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) and
      a.VD in (1890) and
      a.varnum = 1 and
      b.sname = 'cat';
```

This should have the same execution plan.

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

For performance, you want indexes.  Be sure that all the columns in the `ON` clauses have indexes (which they do if they have primary keys).  Then for the `IN` clause, you want an index on `val_tb(valnum, vd, reD)` and perhaps another index for the `where` clause.

Comment: is it possible to optimise it? Maybe left join?

Comment: @dang left join is not optimization, and result rewrited query may be differece. Your query cannot be optimized without knowledge of plans, selectivity, data structure and etc. Check access predicates in the plan of your query, make sure these fields have been indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ANSI** join syntax and avoid the older Oracle join syntax.

```
SELECT a.vd,
       a.vext,
       c.evalu
FROM   val_tb a
       join val_tb d
         ON A.va_record_id = d.red
       join carin b
         ON A.vext = b.source_pos_id
       join mapos c
         ON b.posd = c.posid
WHERE  d.valnum = 100008533
       AND d.vd IN ( 1887, 1890 )
       AND a.varnum = 1
       AND b.sname = 'cat';
```