# Combine 4 queries into 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following queries:

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1890) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'cat'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;

Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1977) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'dog'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;

Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1832) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'mouse'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;

Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1234) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'giraffe'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;
```

How can I combine the above into 1?

Comment: Or the 4 WHERE clauses' differing parts together.

Comment: `UNION` between each select removing `;` at the end would be the easiest.  However there may be a cleaner way

Comment: You didn't apply the `JOIN` as suggested in your previous topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/34201098/3989608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the values (1890,cat), (1977,dog), ... are already stored in database (what i would suggest or otherwise recommend) then determine these values dynamicaly and use a join

```
with data(vd, sname) as
 (select 1977, 'dog' from dual
  union all
  select 1832, 'mouse' from dual
  union all
  select 1890, 'cat' from dual
  union all
  select 1234, 'giraffe' from dual)

Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu
  from val_tb a, carin b, mapos c, data d
 where a.VA_record_id in (Select reD
                            from val_tb
                           where valnum = 100008533
                             and VD = 1887)
   and a.VD = d.vd
   and a.varnum = 1
   and b.sname = d.sname
   and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
   and b.posd = c.posid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.varnum=1
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid

and ((a.VD in(1890) and b.sname = 'cat') OR
     (a.VD in(1977) and b.sname = 'dog') OR
     (a.VD in(1832) and b.sname = 'mouse') OR
     (a.VD in(1234) and b.sname = 'giraffe'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `UNION ALL` them together.

But it would be cleaner to do something like this:

```
Select     a.VD
,          a.VEXT
,          c.evalu 
from       val_tb  a
inner join carin b
       on  a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
inner join mapos c
       on  b.posd = c.posid;
where      a.VA_record_id in (Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
       and a.varnum=1
       and ((a.VD in(1890) and b.sname = 'cat')
            or (a.VD in(1977) and b.sname = 'dog')
            or (a.VD in(1832) and b.sname = 'mouse')
            or (a.VD in(1234) and b.sname = 'giraffe'))
```

Also notice the explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

one approach:

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu 
from val_tb  a
INNER JOIN carin b
  on a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
INNER JOIN mapos c
  on b.posd = c.posid
where a.VA_record_id in (Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.varnum=1
and ((b.sname = 'cat' and a.VD in (1890))
 or  (b.sname = 'dog' and a.VD in (1977))
 or  (b.sname = 'mouse' and a.VD in(1832))
 or  (b.sname = 'giraffe' and a.VD in(1234)))
```

using unions but far more complicated than needs to be.

```
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1890) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'cat'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid
UNION ALL
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1977) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'dog'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid
UNION ALL
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1832) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'mouse'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid
UNION ALL
Select a.VD, a.VEXT, c.evalu from val_tb  a, carin b, mapos c
where a.VA_record_id in 
(Select reD from val_tb  where valnum = 100008533 and VD=1887) 
and a.VD in(1234) 
and a.varnum=1
and b.sname = 'giraffe'
and a.VEXT = b.source_pos_id
and b.posd = c.posid;
```